# How to disable hook in wordpress parent theme from child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook

I need to duplicate a hook from wordpress parent theme to child theme.

How do I disable the hook in wordpress parent theme and call it from child theme?

For example:

```
add_action('lr_header', 'lr_header_fnc');
```

Comment: this could help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623

Comment: Thanks @ArsalanMithani I am looking onto it!

Comment: could not figure it out actualy. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your code plz? both parent child, so we could see what exactly you are trying.

Comment: I haave already resolved it. Thanks for your concern again :)

Comment: then plz post your solution & mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
remove_action('lr_header', 'lr_header_fnc');
```

[remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

Comment: may b? you are not sure & replying?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Doing so in my child theme's functions.php does not actually work or else Do I need to add something else?